# Laravel yield and extends not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

This is master.blade.php placed in views folder

```
<html ng-app="planner">
<head>
    <title>MeetUp Planner</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="row row-centered planner-block">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-centered col-min form-area">
                    <div class="row row-centered">
                        @yield('signup')
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/master.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is forms/signup.blade.php place in views folder

```
@extends('master')

@section('signup')
    <div class="col-md-11 col-centered form-area-inner">
        <span class="form-text">Sign Up</span>
        <hr class="seperator"/>
    </div>
@stop
```

This is routes file

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('master');
});
```

The yield 'signup' is not wokring, the divs and text are not being show in the master file. What could be the problem?

Directory Structure

```
resources:
---views->errors
---views->forms->signup.blade.php
---views->vendor
---views->master.blade.php
```

Using laravel 5.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how it works. `master` view will be extended when you'll use `forms.signup` view:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('forms.signup');
});
```

If you want to include some view into `master` view, you should use [`@include()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#including-sub-views) clause.

Comment: so when do I use yield then, because my master file is not in the forms directory

Comment: your master.blade.php should be in resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri, usually app has master layout which `yields` different `sections` from views which extend this master layout. I'd recommend to read or watch some Blade tutorial, that'll help you to understand how Blade works.

Comment: I didn't notice 'forms.signup', now understood the concept! thanks :) @AlexeyMezenin

Answer (score 0):

your route file will be

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
     return view('forms.signup');
});
?>
```

change the location of master.blade.php

move it to ---resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php

in your master.blade.php file change this line

`@yield('signup')` to  `@yield('content')`

reference link : [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)